# Storing doubles in vector from standard input

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

The doubles are in a text file and are delimited by a space. They are (x,y) cords. The following code doesn't read the line and print the vertices once it is stored.

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    vector < pair < double, double > > verticies;
    double firstDouble , secondDouble;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {

        std::cin >> getline(cin, firstDouble, secondDouble);
        verticies.insert(firstDouble, secondDouble);
        std::cout << verticies::at(i) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "having trouble" means.

Comment: The input is not being stored properly into the vector and because the input is delimited by a space I have no clue how to properly work around that. I have tried to store it like std::cin >> firstDouble >> secondDouble; but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The reason your values aren't stored properly in your vector might be because the code doesn't compile.

Comment: It worked until the first std::cin in the for loop. I had it print out the values of the loop to verify that it compiled, it just has to do with the vector.

Comment: I was looking for help with the printing out values as well because everywhere I searched had verticies.at(i). That is correct it didn't compile I was just stating that everything besides what was in my for loop compiled properly prior to me trying to insert the pair of doubles.

Comment: `verticies.at(i)` wont compile probably because pair has no `operator<<` overload. Instead just do `std::cout << verticies[i].first << " " << verticies[i].second << endl;` or define an overload.

Comment: Either use `emplace` or `make_pair` and `push_back`. Instead of trying to write anything, **you should read the documentation.** And it is not very hard to find that kind of information with Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here:

- You used `std::getline` wrong. Simply write `std::cin >> firstDouble >> secondDouble`.
- `insert` is used to insert elements in the middle of the vector. Use `push_back` or `emplace_back` to append elements to the vector.
- `insert` and `push_back` takes the value of the element to be inserted, which in this case is a pair of doubles (two doubles doesn't automatically become a pair of doubles). Therefore, you need to construct a pair with `std::make_pair` or use `emplace_back`, which takes the arguments to be forwarded to the constructor of the pair.
- `verticies::at(i)` should be `verticies.at(i)`.
- By default, the `<<` operator only knows how to print primitive types like int and double. To print other types, you either need to print its members separately like `std::cout << verticies.at(i).first << ' ' << verticies.at(i).second << '\n'`, or overload the `<<` operator to print a pair.

<sup>(You spelled "vertices" wrong.)</sup>